# selectionSort Javascript animation

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, animation

I'm trying to build a visual representation of some famous sorting algorithms in javascript, but I can't understand why my code doesn't print each iteration even if the print function is in the for loop. I only get the final result.

This is the sorting function, in particular the selection sort algorithm:

```
function selectionSort(array) {
var i, j, min_idx;
let n = array.length;

for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
{
    min_idx = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < array[min_idx])
        {
            min_idx = j;
        }
    }
    var temp = array[min_idx];
    array[min_idx] = array[i];
    array[i] = temp;
    printArray(array);
}

}
```

And this is the printing function:

```
function printArray(array) {
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML ='';
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<div class = "column '+i+'" id = "'+i+'" style = "height: '+array[i]+'px;"></div>';
}

}
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: because you `document.getElementById('container').innerHTML ='';` just before you output

Comment: You are clearing the div every time when calling "printArray". 
`document.getElementById('container').innerHTML ='';`

Comment: you're also not likely to see the content change - since no rendering will be performed by the browser while the sort loop is going - your mileage may vary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's what @Bravo states in the comments. The screen is updates at least 60 times per second, but it takes less time to do the sorting. So you need to add a timeout in a recursive loop so you can actually see the animation.

I replaced the first for loop with this recursive loop. I think the code it self-explanatory.

I did some optimization in your `printArray()`, where it takes time to constantly doing DOM changes. Instead, loop through to create a text string and then add it once to `#container.innerHTML`. There were also some faulty thinking in the value that you gave the visualized divs, where you only added the order (i), instead of adding the actual value (array[i]).

```js
const iterationLegend = document.getElementById('iterations');
const containerDiv    = document.getElementById('container');

const ANIMATION_SPEED = 1000;
const RESTART = 0;

var firstIteration;

function startSelectionSort(array) {
  firstIteration = RESTART;
  selectionSort(array);
}

function selectionSort(array) {
  let min_idx = firstIteration,
      n = array.length;
  
  for (let j = firstIteration + 1; j < n; j++) {
    if (array[j] < array[min_idx]) {
      min_idx = j;
    }
  }

  var temp = array[min_idx];
  array[min_idx] = array[firstIteration];
  array[firstIteration] = temp;

  visualizeArray(array);
  iterationLegend.textContent = 'iteration ' + firstIteration;
    
  if (firstIteration < n - 1) {
    firstIteration++;
    setTimeout(selectionSort.bind(this, array), ANIMATION_SPEED);
  } else {
    iterationLegend.textContent = 'Done';
  }
}

function visualizeArray(array) {
  let elementStr = '';
  let value = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    value = array[i];
    elementStr += `<div class="column${value}" data-value="${value}"></div>`;
  }

  containerDiv.innerHTML = elementStr;
}

startSelectionSort([2, 3, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4]);
```

```css
fieldset {
  display: inline;
}

#iterations {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#container > div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2px 1px 0px;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: brown;
}

.column2 {
  background-color: black;
}

.column3 {
  background-color: teal;
}

.column4 {
  background-color: red;
}

.column5 {
  background-color: indigo;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
 <legend id="iterations">Iterations</legend>
 <div id="container"></div>
</fieldset>
```